Azure Web App Remote Debugging and Deployment Slots
I know I can turn on Remote Debugging for an App Service in the Configuration section. I also get a warning that the app service may restart if I make the change, hence my current hesitation, because I want to avoid that if at all possible.
So two related questions:

Does turning on remote debugging only turn on remote debugging for the selected deployment slot, or is it for all slots?
And two, if it does restart will it only restart the selected deployment slot?


You can see that Debugging option for App service is different for each slot.
Production Slot:

Staging Slot:


Does turning on remote debugging only turn on remote debugging for the selected deployment slot, or is it for all slots?


As you know, to remote debug the debugging option has to be enabled.

Initially both the slot's debugging option is disabled.

I have enabled the Debugging option for the Production Slot.




I don't see any changes applied to the staging slot.



AFAIK, with the above settings it is clear that Changes made to any of the deployment slot will not affect the other slot.


if it does restart will it only restart the selected deployment slot?

From the GitHub link it is clear that

Restarting any deployment slot won’t affect any of the other deployment slots available for the app.
It can indirectly affect the other slots if the App Service Plan does not have enough resources.


Thank you. I didn't have an environment that I could test this on without possibly affecting production.  Never knew that github blog existed, either!

If you have a sample Azure pp Service, you can add one slot by cloning the production slot for testing.
